# Retrieve the first result for each field on sql table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sql table like this:

| code | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 1 | row2 |
| 2 | row3 |
| 2 | row4 |
| 2 | row5 |

I want to retrieve the first description for each 'code'
For ex:

| code | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 2 | row3 |

How can be the SQL query?

Comment: First - according to what?

Comment: with where CODE=xyz

Comment: How do you define which one is first, second, etc? Remember that in relational databases, tables do nor have inherent ordering.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ability to enumerated rows within each `code` with order by `label`.

```
/*
WITH MYTABLE (code, label) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 'row')
, (1, 'row2')
, (2, 'row3')
, (2, 'row4')
, (2, 'row5')
)
*/
SELECT CODE, LABEL
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY LABEL) AS RN_
, T.*
FROM MYTABLE T  
) 
WHERE RN_ = 1
```

| CODE | LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 2 | row3 |